# "Jumped through the fence"

Tags: meaning

"Jumped through the fence" in meaning he jumped over.

Whole sentence: Then he ran across the street, jumped through the fence and walked to the parking lot

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your sentence, none of them render it necessarily incorrect, but still should be considered.

You can either:

A) jump *through* a fence = this you would do if there's a hole in the fence which you are jumping through, for example by executing a *dive roll*

B) jump *over* a fence = this you would do when you are actually jumping *over* the fence

Another thing you should consider is the use of the article preceding the *fence*.

If **the fence** has been already mentioned somewhere in your text and the reader already knows what fence you're talking about, you would say:

> He jumped through the fence.

If it's **a fence** which has not been mentioned before and you are simply talking about *any* fence which was blocking his path, you would say:

> He jumped through a fence.

The last thing you should consider is that fences are meant to stop trespassers, therefore from their very nature it's unnatural they have holes in them for people to jump through, which makes it pretty awkward to say a person jumps *through a fence*. If you want to use the word *through*, you should prepare the reader for the fact that there is a fence with a hole in it by describing the fence before the person jumps it through and *then* marking it as *the fence*. For example:

> As he was running across the street deciding what his next step would be, he noticed a fence with a rather big hole in it. He jumped through the fence and walked to the parking lot.

If you want to stick to your original sentence as much as possible, stick to it, it's grammatically correct, just consider what I wrote above.

Comment: Your last sentence in your post: So I should consider using "throught" when I'm jumping throught bricky fence without hole ?

Comment: I guess you mean a wall, not a fence. Fence cannot be made out of bricks. And no, if it has got no hole in it and you are not destroying the wall by jumping through it and making a hole in it, then no :) You need to say, "He jumped over a wall and walked to the parking lot."

Comment: I have got image which shows rocky-bricky wall. But in text, I have "jumped _____ the fence ...."

Comment: Well, then something is obviously wrong, but the correct answer is definitely "over" :)

Comment: okay, thanks. I had dispute with my teacher. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @genesis: haha, no pozeram ze si z Ciech, co aj vysvetluje ten problem :) asi to tam mate "preskocit cez plot" a preto si pani ucitelka, ktora ocividne o anglictine moc nevie, mysli ze to ma byt "jump through" :))

Comment: @RiMMEr: ono se tu muze mluvit cesky? Omyl, bylo to přesně naopak a ja si myslel ze je to through. Jinak, ty zijes v anglii/USA?

Comment: @genesis: nie, Slovensko :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how, no.  "Jumped through the fence" means just that; either he jumped through a hole that was already in the fence, or jumped at the fence and smashed a hole in it, then fell through.  If you want to say he jumped over the fence, say "he jumped over".

Comment: so if it is bricky wall, it's impossible to jump "throught"?

Comment: Yes, unless there's already a hole in it or you somehow smash a hole in it.

Comment: @genesis Also it's "through", not "throught".

Comment: whoops, sorry. It was typo. Is "typo" in slang or is it wrong as translater did not find that word?:

Comment: I'd classify "typo" as a proper word now, but some wouldn't.  I think it's becoming more standard and will shortly (if it's not already) be widely considered a proper word, yes.

Answer (score 1):

When I read this question I couldn't help but wonder whether there was some confusion between a [**fence**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fence) - which is generally either made of wooden boards or of wire - and a [**hedge**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hedge), which is generally made of bushes trained to grow together to some height.

It would be *very* unusual to jump through a fence - unless there were already a hole in the fence, or unless you were jumping in a car (I have a mental image of the [Dukes of Hazzard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dukes_of_hazzard) [jumping in the ol' General Lee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WK_Vsn4llEI), crashing through a fence and hollering "Yeeeeee-haaaaaw!")  On the other hand, I've seen plenty of references to people - fox-hunters, soldiers, small children - [crashing through hedges](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=crashed%20through%20the%20hedge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3):

> Tunstal was already at the end of the field, and at one spring crashed through the hedge.

([*A Summer Day's Adventure of Three School Boys*, William Howitt, 1833](http://books.google.com/books?id=n20EAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA251&dq=%22crashed%20through%20the%20hedge%22&hl=en&ei=xyUATqirHozGsAOhk52VDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22crashed%20through%20the%20hedge%22&f=false))